# Eclipse still giving me red squiggly lines after I add the libraries to the classpath

Tags: eclipse

I got the libraries that I needed to be recognized by the javac task, but my Eclipse IDE still doesn't "get it" lol.  When I go to Preferences menu, what do I need to point to the library folders to make the red squiggly lines go away? :)

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you "link" the libraries? I do from Project properties (right click on the project, "Properties", then "Java Build Path")...

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the project's properties and specifically to `Java Build Path`. Then add your libraries to the `Libraries` tab.

Comment: +1 Because I had the "green tick" but you were right as well.